# R: Converting "special" letters into UTF-8?

Tags: r, utf-8, character, string-formatting

I run into problems matching tables where one dataframe contains special characters and the other doesn't. Example: Do**ñ**a Ana County vs. Dona Ana County

Here is a script where you can reproduce the outputs:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(acs)
tbl_df(acs::fips.place)    # contains "Do\xf1a Ana County"
tbl_df(tigris::fips_codes) # contains "Dona Ana County"
```

**Example:**

```
tbl_df(tigris::fips_codes) %>% filter(county == "Dona Ana County")
```

returns:

```
# A tibble: 1 x 5
  state state_code state_name county_code          county
  <chr>      <chr>      <chr>       <chr>           <chr>
1    NM         35 New Mexico         013 Dona Ana County
```

Unfortunately, following queries return nothing:

```
tbl_df(acs::fips.place) %>% filter(COUNTY == "Do\xf1a Ana County")
tbl_df(acs::fips.place) %>% filter(COUNTY == "Doña Ana County")
tbl_df(acs::fips.place) %>% filter(COUNTY == "Dona Ana County")

# A tibble: 0 x 7
# ... with 7 variables: STATE <chr>, STATEFP <int>, PLACEFP <int>, PLACENAME <chr>, TYPE <chr>, FUNCSTAT <chr>, COUNTY <chr>
```

However, when opening the dataframe in R Studio, it shows:

[image: Special characters]

**Question 1:** Why does the second query give no return, though "Do\xf1a Ana County" appears in the database?

**Question 2:** How can I convert all "special" characters such as **ñ** into **n**, or similar (UTF-8?)? Is there a library or snippet for that, or definition in the header, instead of defining rules for every character? I would have to do this anyways in order to match certain columns from both tables.

Thank you!

Comment: The problem is that `acs::fips.place` is badly mangled. `\\xf1a` doesn't mean anything; `\xf1a` does (in `latin1` encoding), but converting from one to the other is difficult. If I were you I would report a bug to the `acs` package mantainer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

```
 tbl_df(acs::fips.place) %>% filter(COUNTY == "Do\\xf1a Ana County")
```

In your dataset what you really have is `Do\\xf1a` you can check this in the R console by using for instance :

```
acs::fips.place[grep("Ana",f$COUNTY),]
```

The functions to use are `iconv(x, from = "", to = "")` or
`enc2utf8` or  `enc2native` which don't take a "from" argument.
In most cases to build a package you need to convert data to  UTF-8 (I have to transcode all my French strings when building packages). Here I think it's latin1, but the \ has been escaped.

```
x<-"Do\\xf1a Ana County"
Encoding(x)<-"latin1"
charToRaw(x)
#  [1] 44 6f f1 61 20 41 6e 61 20 43 6f 75 6e 74 79
xx<-iconv(x, "latin1", "UTF-8")
charToRaw(xx)
# [1] 44 6f c3 b1 61 20 41 6e 61 20 43 6f 75 6e 74 79
```

Finally if you need to clean up your output to get comparable strings you can use this function (straight from my own encoding hell).

```
to.plain <- function(s) {   
   #old1 <- iconv("èéêëù","UTF8") #use this if your console is in LATIN1
   #new1 <- iconv("eeeeu","UTF8") #use this if your console is in LATIN1
  old1 <- "èéêëù"
  new1 <- "eeeeu"
  s1 <- chartr(old1, new1, s)      
}
```

Comment: I will mark as solved once I learn there's no better way. I'm a bit surprised it needs so many steps to solve the issue.

Comment: Some sources on encoding [rstudio](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200532197-Character-Encoding),
[encoding hell](http://people.fas.harvard.edu/~izahn/posts/reading-data-with-non-native-encoding-in-r/), 
[Encodings in R 2.1.0](https://developer.r-project.org/Encodings_and_R.html)

Comment: `gsub("\\\\\\\\","\\", "Do\\xf1a Ana County")` does nothing. `stringi::stri_trans_general` provides robust and gerneral transliteration; there is no need to write your own `to.plain` function.

Comment: +1 You are absolutely right, I spent some time reading to figure out that \\ is similar to \ in R and I don't need to do it. As usuall I answered a bit too quickly and I will remove this line. Also thanks for pointing out the stringi::stri_trans_general I will use it from now on, my own function (and encoding troubles) are way older than this package though...

Answer (score 2):

The first problem is that `acs::fips.place` is badly mangled; if provides e.g., `\\xf1a` where it means `\xf1a`. A bug should be reported to the package mantainer. In the meantime, here is one work-around:

```
tbl_df(acs::fips.place) %>%
    mutate(COUNTY = scan(text = str_c(COUNTY, collapse = "\n"),
                         sep = "\n",
                         what = "character",
                         allowEscapes = TRUE)) -> fp

Encoding(fp$COUNTY) <- "latin1"

fp %>%
    filter(COUNTY == "Doña Ana County")
```

Once the escapes have been cleaned up you can transliterate non-ascii characters into ascii substitutions. The `stringi` package makes it easy:

```
library(stringi)
fp$COUNTY <- stri_trans_general(fp$COUNTY, "latin-ascii")

fp %>%
    filter(COUNTY == "Dona Ana County")
```

Comment: That creates "Do<U+00F1>a Ana County"?

Comment: That is probably a different bug (in R itself). You can ignore it (it only affects the printed representation) or skip the `iconv` step. (I labelled the `iconv` step optional for exactly this reason.)

Comment: I've now removed the `iconv` part and added an answer to the second question.